# Why do I get big number occasionally wherever I call Smart Contract functions using web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, dapps

I have column named total balance, which has a type of uint and function named getBalance which return its balance and the corresponding functionality has been also declared in Web3js..They get called automatically on page load..
Now Whenever I refresh the page, I get

> **3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331.534351508065746944**

sometimes not always..What is the case behind these ?? is it network issue or some error in my code.

> **Solidity**

```
mapping(address => uint) public balances;

modifier onlyRegistered(address _userAddress) {
    require(isUserExists(_userAddress), "User Doesn't exists");
        _;
    }
function getBalance() onlyRegistered(msg.sender) external view returns(uint) {
     return balances[msg.sender];
 }
```

> **Web3js**

```
contract.getBalance((err, balance) => {
  if (balance) {
    // var newBal = balance.toLocaleString();
    var newBal = web3.utils.fromWei(balance.toFixed(), "ether");
    // var newBal = web3.utils.toDecimal(balance);
    $(".user_balance").text(newBal);
    console.log(newBal);
  }
});
```

Comment: Debug suggestion: `console.log(err);` and `console.log(balance.toFixed());` at the very beginning of the function.

Comment: I did..What is got was the same number on the console

Comment: Remove the error-message that you have in the `onlyRegistered` modifier, recompile the contract and try again. Earlier versions of web3.js have an issue with revert-messages executed from constant functions (i.e., when a `require` or `revert` statement which contains an error-message is executed from a `pure` or `view` function). Those versions of web3.js interpret the error-message as the value returned from the function. And your version of web3.js is obviously very old - 0.x - which came out before Solidity even started to support revert-messages.

Comment: More generally, I would suggest getting rid of reverting modifiers on constant functions, being that such functions don't change anything on the blockchain anyway, so there's typically no reason to revert them.

Comment: @goodvibration So, according to you, what should be used instead of require/revert statements..!

Comment: Just get rid of the error-message and make sure that it solves the problem. If it does, I'm not saying that you have to get rid of the `require` statement. I just suggested not to use it in read-only functions, but it's your call to make. In your case, for example, I would simply let the function return the actual balance of the non-authorized user, which is just gonna be zero.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you for suggestion..yea, it would be appropriate to just declared zero instead

Comment: More interestingly - has removing the error-message alone (while keeping the `require` statement in place) solved your problem?

Comment: @goodvibration Nope..I do still get the big number I mentioned..